# Retrieve list of top user tags on data.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer, data-dump

I am currently trying to replicate the query behind the top users page for a certain tag, specifically the "All time" list, in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/494336/top-50-tag-contributors) on data.stackexchange.

The query is as below

```
DECLARE @tagName nvarchar(35) = '##tagName##'

SELECT TOP 50 
    TagName,
    COUNT(*) AS UpVotes,
    Users.DisplayName as UserName,
    number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TagName)
FROM Tags
    INNER JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.TagId = Tags.id
    INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.ParentId = PostTags.PostId
    INNER JOIN Votes ON Votes.PostId = Posts.Id and VoteTypeId = 2
    INNER JOIN Users ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Users.Id
WHERE 
    Tags.TagName = @tagName
    AND Posts.CommunityOwnedDate IS NULL
GROUP BY TagName, DisplayName
ORDER BY UpVotes DESC
```

However, comparing against real lists, it returns higher values per user.

As an example, on the [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven) tag, the first [All time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/maven/topusers) top user is currently [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) with a score of 2,253, while the query above fetches 2323.

I used as reference similar queries like:

- [How many upvotes do I have for each tag?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag)
- [How many upvotes do I have towards tag-specialist badges?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/2357/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-towards-tag-specialist-badges)

**Question**: how to get the query aligned with the official All time list?

Comment: You only seem to take upvotes into account but not downvotes (votetypeid = 3). Maybe [this answer of mine on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234749/158100) helps

Comment: @rene argh, silly me, indeed I completely forgot about downvotes!

Comment: You're one of the happy few that forget about downvotes then ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, here is the query I came up with:

```
DECLARE @tagName nvarchar(35) = '##tagName##'

SELECT top 50
    TagName,
    SUM(case votes.votetypeid 
            WHEN 2 THEN 1  -- upvote
            WHEN 3 THEN -1  -- downvote
            END) as Rep,
    Users.DisplayName as UserName,
    number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TagName)
FROM Tags
    INNER JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.TagId = Tags.id
    INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.ParentId = PostTags.PostId
    INNER JOIN Users ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Users.Id                
    INNER JOIN Votes ON Votes.PostId = Posts.Id
WHERE Tags.TagName = @tagName
    AND Posts.CommunityOwnedDate IS NULL
GROUP BY TagName, DisplayName
ORDER BY Rep DESC
```

Which gives as example on the [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven) tag, the following [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/maven/topusers):

```
TagName Rep     UserName             number
maven   2256    khmarbaise           1
maven   1792    Raghuram             2
maven   1418    Sean Patrick Floyd   3
maven   1195    Pascal Thivent       4
```

---

**Additional note**: a further improvement would be to also add the number of answers, especially concerning the ordering: in case of equal reputation, the lowest answers count wins.

Comment: I've updated the query to make it possible to adjust the limit, and to include links to the user accounts: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/708168/top-n-answerers-for-a-given-tag