# Who has the most reputation points for python3.x tag?

Tags: support, reputation

I would like to follow the gurus who have the most reputation points for [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag. If I read through their answers about [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) I think after some time this can give me some in-depth understanding of the language.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.x/topusers

Comment: If you click on the tag, it shows the tag page. Within the box at the top of that page is a link to the same place as @vaultah's comment.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325827/retrieve-list-of-top-user-tags-on-data-stackexchange-com

Comment: From the meta meta: [How to find top users by tag?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/145386)

Comment: python-3.x is only a sub-tag of python. Python tag is probably more relevant (but same Martjin will probably come out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [@vaultah](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2301450/vaultah):

> https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.x/topusers

(Currently Martijn Pieters with roughly 3.5x as high a score as the next closest person)